# Are there tricks for detecting whether a `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie went wrong and, if so, delivering additional messages explaining the issue?

Tags: macros, tex-core, csname, error-writing

For the sake of having expandable tokens expanded before stringification I sometimes combine `\csname..\endcsname`-expansion with `\string` as in

```tex
\chardef\stopromannumeral=`\^^00
\edef\gobbleToPrefix{%
  \def\noexpand\gobbleToPrefix##1\string X\string Y{\stopromannumeral}%
}%
\gobbleToPrefix
...
\def\macroA#1{%
   ...
   \expandafter\macroB\expandafter{%
     \romannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter
     \expandafter           \gobbleToPrefix
     \expandafter\string
     \csname XY#1\endcsname
   }%
   ...
}%
% A macro where the argument must be a string of catcode-12-characters
% and catcode-10-spaces:
\def\macroB#1{%
  <replacement text where #1 occurs as placeholder for a string>
}%
```

In case `\macroA`'s #1 contains things which should not occur between `\csname..\endcsname` you get error-messages which are hard to understand for people not familiar to TeX.

Are there tricks for detecting whether the `\csname..\endcsname`-thingie went wrong and, if so, delivering additional messages explaining the issue?

Comment: not  really although if you throw on a `\detokenize` you will always avoid a low level csname error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but `\detokenize` prevents expansion... ;-)

Comment: You could just use `\string\xy#1`.  If \xy#1 is not a leagl name, then `\expandafter\string\csname xy#1\endcsname` will not be legal either.

Comment: @UlrichDiez You can use something like `\detokenize\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}` with most modern engines.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think I don't get your point. The only reason for the `\gobbleToPrefix`-thing is getting rid of the escape-character produced due to `\string` no matter what the current value of the `\escapechar`-parameter is. Also no harm should be done in case no escape-character at all is produced by `\string` as `\escapechar`'s value is negative.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Or `\expanded{\noexpand\detokenize{#1}}`. ;-)  I just looked in the mirror and did a facepalm at myself... This might even turn out nicely in terms of yielding error-messages in case a malevolent user did s.th. like `\macroA{\endcsname hope this breaks unnoticed!\csname relax}`. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please forget my comment about `\detokenize` preventing expansion. I often forget about new things like `\expanded`.

Comment: If you are using LuaTeX you can simply use `\csstring`, instead of `\gobbleToPrefix` .

Comment: The prettiest way to write the `\expanded` thing is to use `\detokenize\expanded{{#1}}` (and this should also be the fastest), note that `\expanded{\noexpand\detokenize{#1}}` needs two steps of expansion whereas the other two variants need only a single step.